# How to setup custom actions for google assistant when coding in flutter

Tags: flutter, actions-on-google

I am trying to implement Google Assistant for custom actions inside my app using flutter. The scenario is to deeplink to a specific feature of an activity when requested to google assistant

I have implemented this requirement successfully in native android using java and kotlin but i cannot find any document related to flutter.

Let me explain the login.

1. create actions.xml in res -> xml folder.

   ```
   <actions>
     <action intentName="actions.intent.VIEW">
   ​
       <fulfillment urlTemplate="digital.example/abcd">
       ​
       ​ <parameter-mapping
         intentParameter="exercise.name"
         urlParameter="exerciseType" />
       ​
   </fulfillment>
   ​
     </action>
   </actions>
   ```
2. create Deeplinks from the tools -> App link Assistant which are added in the fullfillment tag in step 1.

Update your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="digital.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/abcd" />
        </intent-filter>

<!-- Add an indication where to find the actions.xml -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.actions"
        android:resource="@xml/actions" />
```

3. Test Using  Tools -> App Actions Test Tool.

But I am not getting any help documentation if i want to implement in flutter.

P.S -> I am also going to implement the same in Siri(iOS)

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm looking for exactly the same info as well.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to accomplish this in Flutter. https://fidev.io/ok-google-flutter/